# Zend Framework Error:Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm using the Zend Frameworker 1.12.

According to the help file, I used the Zend_Db_Statement to execute my sql.

Below is my php code:

```
 $sql = "delete from options where id=?";
 $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($this->getAdapter(), $sql);
 return $stmt->execute(array('1'));
```

But the error is exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound' in D:\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.zend.php.framework.resource\resources\ZendFramework-1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Mysqli.php:209
Stack trace:

.........
.........

I googled for days, but nothing works.

Any one know how to fix it?

Comment: The fact that you get a `PDOException` while working with a _Mysqli class makes me think you should be using `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo` instead. Can you provide the output of `\Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($this->getAdapter())); die;`? In any case, to prevent 'hard coding' mistakes like this, use `$this->getAdapter()->query($sql, array('1'));` instead, which should automatically use the correct classes and will internally prepare and bind the parameters for you.

Comment: run Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($this->getAdapter())), it outputs the 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code uses the class `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli` but your connection is not a 'mysqli' connection. It is a Pdo_Mysql connection. This causes the code to fail. You can fix your code by replacing `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli` with `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo`. However, a better solution would be the following:

```
$sql = "delete from options where id=?";
$this->getAdapter()->query($sql, array('1'));
```

This should automatically use the correct classes (regardless of the type of your database connection) and will take care of different steps internally.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "delete from options where id=?";
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($this->getAdapter(), $sql);
return $stmt->execute(array(1 => '1'));
```

Comment: Did you use model classes? Create your own table class and extend it from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. Then you can delete some record using delete() method.

Comment: yes, i use the model class and extends the Zend_Db_Table. I know I can use the delete method. I just want to exectue sql.

Comment: In case you are using model try this code:
$table->getAdapter()
   ->query('DELETE FROM `options` WHERE `id` = ?')
   ->execute(array(1 => 1));